# Trying to call a js function inside PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm running a PHP code to validate login form and if there's an input empty it should run a javscript function that changes the display attribute of some DIVs to block.
  If I put my JS code between the head tag it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

, and If I put my code before the /body tag it says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: formValidation is not defined

Javascript code:

```
function formValidation() {
     document.getElementById("errMessage").style.display = "block",
    document.getElementById("arrow-errMessage").style.display = "block",
    document.getElementById("errEmail").style.display = "block",
    document.getElementById("arrow-errEmail").style.display = "block"; 
}
```

PHP code:

```
else {
          echo "<script> formValidation(); </script>";
    }
```

Comment: it is better to validate form in function using if else statements, and then alert the user about the empty and then focus to that field and add css instead doing this in php with JavaScript. if php and JavaScript are separate then it is also easy to handle the errors.

Comment: If you're running the validation through PHP, why aren't you setting those styles directly by PHP...? I'm very much suspecting a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/13840431/476 here...

Answer (score 1):

At the time you execute `formValidation()` the DOM elements are not ready.
You need to catch the page load event and then execute the style change.

```
document.addEventListener("load", formValidation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
window.onload=formValidation;
```

It is executed when web page has completely loaded all content.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) for checking document ready event.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

Use this HTML code in your document

```php
else{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       formValidation();
    });
</script>';
}
```

Edit your php code and try this